# Subscribe to multiple specific tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags, subscription

I need to subscribe to specific tags, for example:

If I need to subscribe to the `[android]` tag I just go through this tag and subscribe to it. What if I need to make it more specific, like `[android][java]` which will send me emails with the questions containing these tags only (meaning I won't receive separate emails for `[android]` only or `[java]` only)?

Is that possible or not?

Comment: Therefore, it's not possible.